# Looking for documentation to get device information in C++ for the PS4 platform

Tags: c++, device, ps4

I'm working in a project to harvest the device information for the PS4 platform, in C++. This includes information such as device manufacturer, model, firmware version, machine unique id, OS information, CPU & GPU information and other hardware information. For Windows, we have APIs and documentation to do this(we may write programs to read from the registry as well). So far, I haven't been able to find any such documentation related to PS4. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does PS4 let random people write games? I know in the past, you had to have an agreement with Sony.

Comment: As far as I know, you will get access to the SDK and documentation when you get a developer license. There are limits to what you’re allowed to do, and I doubt that Sony likes the idea of “harvesting”.

Answer (score 1):

You have to **be partners** with them, like ***Naughty Dog***.

Look at this page: https://partners.playstation.net/

Comment: Thanks. I've requested to become a partner and join the developer group.